# I need to program GUIin matlab to check for data in serial port, continously

Tags: matlab, user-interface, loops

I am a beginner in GUI, MatLab. I need to program GUI to check for data in serial port, continuosly. Meanwhile my GUI should be capable to other functions also. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely start [here.](http://www.mathworks.com/discovery/matlab-gui.html) There is everything you need to start designing GUIs with Matlab.